# how to compare two collection and get match records

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am using Laravel and I have two different collections that contain ID of products

First one is `colorProduct` and second is `tagProduct`

so I want to compare these two and get only same ID of products so how can I do this?

```php
$colorProducts = Color::where('code', $request->color)->get()->first()->products;

$tagProducts = $tag->products->where('shop_id', $shop->id);

$colorAndTagProducts = collect();

foreach ($colorProducts->toBase()->merge($tagProducts)->unique('id')->groupBy('id') as $allProducts) {
    if ($allProducts->count() >= 1) {
        $colorAndTagProducts[] = $allProducts->first();
    }
}
```

here

> $colorAndTagProducts

gives me all records form both collection but I only want same record

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, if I understand correctly, but maybe like this?
I suppose Color and Product are in many to many relationship. And Product and Shop/tag in one to many.

```
$colorId = Color::where('code', $request->color)->get()->first()->id;
$shopId = $shop->id;

$products = Product::whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($colorId) {
                $query->where('id', $colorId); //id or color_id
            })->where('shop_id', $shopId)->get();
```

Comment: I just want to compare two collections

Comment: By "compare" you mean what? Show items that are in one collection, but arent in second? Or you want only items, that are in both collections?

Comment: If you want only items, that are in both collections, than my answer is correct. This will select all products that have color set in request (`$request->color`) and have shop_id `$shop->id`.

Comment: You can just use whereHas `$query->where('colors.code', $request->color)`

Answer (score 0):

```
intersect()
```

> The intersect method removes any values from the original collection
>   that are not present in the given array or collection. The resulting
>   collection will preserve the original collection's keys:

I did it with this method